# Can't plot Scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, k-means, scatter-plot

Help i don't understand why i can't print a scatterplot. I can print the figure with the grid and the axes but it's empty

```
def kmeans(data, k, genre1, genre2):
  data = data.loc[:, [genre1,genre2]].values
  km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=5, random_state=0)
  y_means = km.fit_predict(data)

  centroids = km.cluster_centers_  
  print(centroids)
  labels = km.labels_
  u_labels = np.unique(labels)
  cluster_name = ["Cluster"+str(i) for i in set(labels)]
  print(cluster_name)

  # Plot Figure
  #mpl.style.use('seaborn')
  plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
  for i in u_labels:
    plt.scatter(data[labels == i , 0] , data[labels == i , 1] , label = i)

  plt.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], s = 60, c = 'red' , label = 'centeroid')

  plt.xlabel(genre1 + ' Average Ratings')
  plt.ylabel(genre2 + ' Average Ratings')
  plt.xlim([1, 5])
  plt.ylim([1, 5])
  plt.title(genre1 + ' vs ' + genre2)
  ax = plt.axes()
  ax.set_facecolor("gainsboro")
  plt.show()
```

[image: Here's the output]

I'm in a hurry with this project, i really hope for someone's answer soon

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Where are you trying to print this (in what environment? A console? A JupyterLab notebook in a browser? A JupyterLab notebook in Idea or Code? You also haven't provided any info on what this function is acting on — what data source are you using? How are you getting it?

Comment: I am using python 3.7 on Google Colab, the parameters are a Pandas dataframe that contains the mean of ratings given by users to certain movie genres, k is the number of clusters i want to get (11), genre 1 and 2 are strings with the name of the genres i'm considering

Comment: You have drawn two scatter plots, can you invalidate the second scatter plot and draw the first one? Can I disable the second scatterplot and draw the first scatterplot and vice versa? I need to isolate the error from there.

Comment: In the `for i in u_labels` loop is `data[labels == i , 0]` *returning* anything? Maybe try `data.loc[labels == i , 0]` or `data.iloc[labels == i , 0]`.

Comment: Nevermind, i managed to do it by calling plt.close() before the first scatterplot and by deleting the line that sets the facecolor. Not sure which one fixed it

Comment: It was probably calling plt.close()

Answer (score 0):

From the picture in your example, it looks like the data is outside the x bounds you set. Comment out the `xlim` and `ylim` lines and let Matplotlib figure out the scaling.

```
def kmeans(data, k, genre1, genre2):
    data = data.loc[:, [genre1,genre2]].values
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=5, random_state=0)
    y_means = km.fit_predict(data)
  
    centroids = km.cluster_centers_  
    print(centroids)
    labels = km.labels_
    u_labels = np.unique(labels)
    cluster_name = ["Cluster"+str(i) for i in set(labels)]
    print(cluster_name)
  
    # Plot Figure
    #mpl.style.use('seaborn')
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
    ax.set_facecolor("gainsboro")
    
    ax.scatter(centroids[:,0], centroids[:,1], s = 60, c = 'red' , label = 'centeroid')
    for i in u_labels:
        ax.scatter(data[labels == i , 0] , data[labels == i , 1] , label = i)
  
  
    plt.xlabel(genre1 + ' Average Ratings')
    plt.ylabel(genre2 + ' Average Ratings')
    #plt.xlim([1, 5])
    #plt.ylim([1, 5])
    plt.title(genre1 + ' vs ' + genre2)
    
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

---

Using fake data:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [1,1],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0],[10,1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['a','b'])
# print(df)
kmeans(df,2,'a','b')
```

---

[image: it works]